# Getting controls from [WebStatic] methods in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

This gives me an exception of Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of Object 
What i am trying to do here is to call this static method from my javascript onblur function . I think the controls are not present there that's why i am getting this issue any help that how can i make this method work and i got alot of asp.net controls in my asp.net web static method .

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static void gXX(int x)
    {  
 if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
                DropDownList t2 = (DropDownList)page.FindControl("t2");
                DropDownList t3 = (DropDownList)page.FindControl("t3");




if (!t2.Text.Equals(""))
                {
                    // this.t3.Items.Clear();
                    DataRow[] dr = ds.Tables["s12"].Select("jsaid = '" + t2.SelectedValue.Trim().ToString() + "'");
                    if (!dr.Length.ToString().Equals("0"))
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow row in dr)
                        {

                            t3.Items.Add(row["c12"].ToString().Trim());

                        }
                    }    
                  }
```

And i am calling this method in my JavaScript like

```
onblur="t2_Leavee();"

 function t2_Leavee() {
 PageMethods.gXX('0');
}
```

Comment: You can't access **Page Controls** inside an static method. Perform an **ajax** call and pass the selected dropdown values as parameter.

Comment: Like how ? i am not getting what your trying to say

Comment: Whats your requirement?  Using **WebMethod** what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Follow this link [WebMethod using Jquery](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) Hope this solves you **Object Reference Issue**.

Comment: Basically i want to populate one dropdown value on the base of other dropdown value and all my dropdown values are coming from dataset . When dropdown losses focus

Comment: If that the case, Then WebMethod won't help you out, Make dataset as static instead of creating a static method. Create an **selectedindexchanged** event for dropdown1 and in that method you can filter out data from Dataset and then populate Dropdown2.

Comment: that's a good suggestion let me work on that . I will comment here for any query :) Thanks mate